# How can I make svn log show commit that were only made to certain files?

Tags: svn

Not sure how I should word this, but I change a file in svn and had some issues with commit so I just made

```
svn commit -m "message" project_folder/file.py
```

and when I do svn log project_folder, it does not show up:

```
svn log project_folder
// shows only the version before I commited file.py
```

However if I do svn log project_folder/file.py, it show the commit.

Is the a way to fix this so that the commits that were only made to certain files also shows up when I do svn log project_folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do `svn update project_folder`.